# How to save a new created DOM document file as .xml in java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I create a new DOM document file using following lines of code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    File file = iniFilePath.toFile();
    if (file.exists()) {
        doc = builder.parse(file);

    } else {
        doc = builder.newDocument();
        doc.appendChild(doc.createElement("windows"));
        //I want to save .xml here
    }
```

Now, I want to save the new created DOM document to an `.xml` file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use transformers :

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Result output = new StreamResult( new File("path_to_xml.xml") );
Source input = new DOMSource( doc );
transformer.transform( input, output );
```